# How to create Advanced "Read More" Using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

How create the 'Read More' Feature For more than 1 elements inside the parent elements

For Example:

```
    <div class="readmore">
        <h1>this Level 1 heading</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,</p>
    </div>
```

From the above code i want to display only 100 character from 'readmore' div after that i want to display "Read More" Link

I also tried this code [Click](http://code-tricks.com/jquery-read-more-less-example/)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to wrap the text you don't want initially displayed in a <div> (give it a logical name) and set the "display" css property for that div to hidden. Then in the "read more" link, there's no actual destination, just an action that sets the "display" style on the div to be displayed to "inline" and the "display" style on the "read more" link to "hidden". If you want to toggle the extra text, it's a bit more complicated, but not terribly so. The key is the "display" css attribute.

Answer (score 0):

below code will do trick for you. Please note I have made some changes to html structure. Working code ***[here](http://jsfiddle.net/sd9coLru/)***

```
var charcount =100;

$('#more').click(function(){debugger;
    $('#actualtext').html($('#readmore').html().substr(0, charcount));
    charcount+=charcount;

    if($('#actualtext').html().length == $('#readmore').html().length){
        $('#more').hide();
    }                                                 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this script :

```
function OkInfoDialog(thisTitle, thisText) {
//-------set the dialog window starting properties
$("#OkInfoDialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, width: '800px', show: 'slideDown', hide: 'slideUp',
    closeOnEscape: false,
    buttons:
    {
        "OK": function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
            $("#loading").fadeOut();
        }
    }
});//-------call for the dialog
$("#OkInfoDialogText").html(thisText);     //write the text in the text area
$("#OkInfoDialog").dialog('option', 'title', thisTitle).dialog('open'); //set the title and open the dialog
```

}

jquery dialog - OkInfoDialog(title, text)
    This dialog receives title and text strings to be used in creating informative dialog windows with only
    an OK button option.  The user is returned back to the sending form with no changes having been made.

Then you can call this script on your page by:

```
<a href="javascript: OkInfoDialog('Title here', '<br/>All more information you want to view ' );"  >more info</a>
```

Comment: can you post your code on jsfiddle, i could n't understand your code